# Syntax Error when reading my html file from fileReader

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am fairly new to node.js so I apologize if I am just ignorant of some of the fundamentals. I am trying to load a web page with a map that takes in data from several JSON files stored in a directory. To push this I need to iterate over the directory the JSON files are in using FileSystem. Currently I am attempting to render my html file from my app.js file as shown in the code below. The problem is when I go to localhost:8000 the html does not render and I am given the following errors in the console
[image]

I have tried replacing the HTML file that I am attempting to render with a basic one containing just an h1 tag and the page renders correctly. With this in mind I have determined I must have something in my html file that requires specification to properly load. Here is my relevant code:

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Interactive Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/Map.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<body onload="getTrips();">

    <div id= "trips"></div>

    <div id="Map" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>



     <!-- My Javascript file -->
     <script src="../Javascript/Map.js"></script>
    <!-- Google Maps JS API -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=myMap"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Node.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

function onRequest(req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  fs.readFile('../HTML/Map.html', null, function(error, data){
    if(error){
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.write("file not found");
    }
    else{
      res.write(data);
    }
    res.end();
  });
  // res.end();
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000);
```

Not sure it makes a difference or not but also note I've removed my API key from the google maps api script tag. In my actual code the script tag contains a key.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue is that you are not handling the requests for the other files (JS/CSS). Your html just doesn't have text or color so you can't see it but if you inspect the page it's there.

Both requests return the html which causes the errors.

Just send the correct file and it should work.

Here's something I threw together.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

function onRequest(req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  let fileName = "";

  if(req.url === "/") {
      fileName = '/Map.html';
  } else {
      fileName = req.url;
  }
  console.log(fileName);
  fs.readFile(`.${fileName}`, null, function(error, data){
    if(error){
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.write("file not found");
    }
    else{
      res.write(data);
    }
    res.end();
  });
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(80);
```

P.S. I recommend express if you are trying to build a node server quickly: https://expressjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have not implemented a solution yet but I've determined that at least a chunk of my errors are due to the fact that my html makes calls to css and javascript files that are not accessible at localhost:8000. To fix this I will have to route to them in my app.js file using express or something similar.

Comment: From the error message above I would guess that instead of `Map.js` you're getting some 404 html document.